# SocketException адрес не совместим с протоколом

Tags: c#, websocket

Пытаюсь сделать что-то типа прокси сервера для блокировки ресурсов по хосту. Здесь творится для меня что-то не объяснимое. Иногда сайт грузится, когда не грузится и вылетает ошибка

> `SocketException` адрес не совместим с протоколом.

Ошибка выскакивает в `myRerouting.Connect(myIPEndPoint);`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. 
Вот сам код:

```
class Program
{
    private static string[] _BlackList = { "vkontakte.ru", "vk.com",     "odnoklassniki.ru", "facebook.com" };



static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // слушаем локальный апишник (127.0.0.1) и порт 8888
  TcpListener myTCP = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
  // поехали!
  myTCP.Start();

  while (true)
  {
    // смотрим, есть запрос или нет
    if (myTCP.Pending())
    {
      // запрос есть
      // передаем его в отдельный поток
      Thread t = new Thread(ExecuteRequest);
      t.IsBackground = true;
      t.Start(myTCP.AcceptSocket());
    }
  }

  myTCP.Stop();
}

private static void ExecuteRequest(object arg)
{
  Socket myClient = (Socket)arg;
  // соединяемся
  if (myClient.Connected)
  {
    // получаем тело запроса
    byte[] httpRequest = ReadToEnd(myClient);
    // ищем хост и порт
    Regex myReg = new Regex(@"Host: (((?<host>.+?):(?<port>\d+?))|(?<host>.+?))\s+", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match m = myReg.Match(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpRequest));
    string host = m.Groups["host"].Value;

            int port = 0;
    // если порта нет, то используем 80 по умолчанию
    if (!int.TryParse(m.Groups["port"].Value, out port)) { port = 80; }

    // получаем апишник по хосту
    IPHostEntry myIPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

    // создаем точку доступа
    IPEndPoint myIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(myIPHostEntry.AddressList[0], port);

    // создаем сокет и передаем ему запрос
    using (Socket myRerouting = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
    {
      myRerouting.Connect(myIPEndPoint);
      if (myRerouting.Send(httpRequest, httpRequest.Length, SocketFlags.None) != httpRequest.Length)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("При отправке данных удаленному серверу произошла ошибка...");
      }
      else
      {
                    if (_BlackList != null && Array.IndexOf(_BlackList, host.ToLower()) != -1)
                    {
                        byte[] response = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 19\r\n\r\nDostup zapreschen!");
                        myClient.Send(response, response.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {


                        // получаем ответ
                        byte[] httpResponse = ReadToEnd(myRerouting);
                        // передаем ответ обратно клиенту
                        if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.Length > 0)
                        {
                            myClient.Send(httpResponse, httpResponse.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        }
                    }
      }
    }
    myClient.Close();
  }
}

private static byte[] ReadToEnd(Socket mySocket)
{
  byte[] b = new byte[mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
  int len = 0;
  using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
  {
    while (mySocket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead) && (len = mySocket.Receive(b, mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
    {
      m.Write(b, 0, len);
    }
    return m.ToArray();
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На *Windows 7, Windows 8* метод [Dns.GetHostEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.addressfamily(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает ip-адреса **IPv6**. Поэтому вы не можете подключиться к сокету, поддерживающий **IPv4**(InterNetwork) через ip-адрес **IPv6**(InterNetworkV6).

Попробуйте создавать сокет следующим способом, используя [AddressFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.addressfamily(v=vs.110).aspx) для полученного IP.

```
    using (Socket myRerouting = new Socket(myIPEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
    {
      myRerouting.Connect(myIPEndPoint);
      ....

    }
```

Comment: Все отлично, работает. На ресурсы выбранные не заходит, но вот на другие, которые не https, броузер выдает просто белый лист. Может знаете в чем проблема?